# SQL select non null value

Tags: mysql

```
Customer_name   Customer_street Customer_city

Lucy            Spring          Pittsfield
Lucy            Spring          Pittsfield
Brooks          Senator         Brooklyn
James           North           Rye
Vicky           Sand Hill       Woodside
Lutz            3399 Rice St    null
```

I am practicing on some command of mysql. I have a customer table above. I want to list customer city names from that table but list only those non-null city names. I tried

```
select customer_city 
from customer 
WHERE customer_city IS NOT NULL;
```

The result still list the null city. Am I missing something? Thank you for your help;

Comment: Is the city really `NULL`, or is it the string `'null'`?

Comment: OMG, Barmar, I didn't think about that possibility, lol..

Comment: the city name is NULL

Comment: Works fine here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6964/1

Comment: hmm, i did exactly like that but still list the null in the result

Comment: and if you modify your where clause by WHERE customer_city IS NOT NULL AND customer_city <> 'null';  If it works then it means you have string 'null' in your database as Barmar have suggested above. Because it seems there is a problem the value stored for customer Lutz.

Comment: @Nico thank you. Actually, it was a string :) I got it now

Comment: happy to have help you :)